# MySQL Counting the number of distinct results

Tags: php, mysql, count, concatenation

How do I find out the total number of results for each DISTINCT CONCAT in MySQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (h, ' - ', a) AS ft FROM raw_score
```

This works and gives me a result like this
1 - 0
2 - 2
1 - 1
0 - 1

but I also want to know how many times that final score has happened eg 1 - 0 could have happened 10 times

For each result I am querying the database again with this

```
SELECT COUNT(CONCAT(h, ' - ', a) AS ft_total) 
FROM raw_score 
WHERE ft_total = 'result_from_previous_query'
```

but its not working

Many thanks for any help

Comment: [COUNT DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)?

Answer (score 2):

```
select ft, count(*)
from (
   SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (h, ' - ', a) AS ft 
   FROM raw_score
) t
group by ft
```

or merged into a single query:

```
SELECT CONCAT (h, ' - ', a) AS ft, count(*)
FROM raw_score
group by CONCAT (h, ' - ', a)
```